# Headless Chrome --print-to-pdf with asian fonts

Tags: java, google-chrome, ubuntu, pdf, fonts

I have a Java micro-service where a list of urls can be converted to PDF using headless `Chrome` with the `--print-to-pdf` option. This works well on my local Windows and on an ubuntu server it works for Latin fonts. But when I try to do this with a website with Asian fonts it fails. I assumed the fonts are simply missing on the server, but I installed them into `/usr/local/share/fonts` and also to `/usr/share/fonts`, just to be sure. I refreshed the font cache with `fc-cache -f -v` and then restarted the java service. But still it does not work.
So:

- is this a Java problem? How to tell Java to take these fonts (on Windows it just seems to work)
- is this a Chrome issue, e.g. do I have to provide fonts to the process somehow?
- is this an ubuntu issue: Do I maybe need to install the fonts for the user running the service somehow?
- What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a few hours of try and error I found the solution within a post. Apparently headless chrome on ubuntu needs some additional fonts. One simple install solves the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto
```

Comment: You may accept your own answer if this solved your problem. That helps to let other people know it has been solved.